# How does the symbiotic bacteria reaches a human caecum

Tags: bacteriology, digestive-system, symbiosis

My thought on this matter is that we have got a very high pH of about 1.8 in our stomach.So,most of bacteria who came in through food or just open mouth should be killed by it.So,how does a bacterial fauna builds up in caecum.

Comment: key word "most"

Comment: What do you mean,I couldn't quite get you.Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Your own words "most of bacteria who came in ... should be killed..." key word in that sentence is "most" Some preliminary research on your part is expected, I suggest googling "human gut flora"